# Generic casting / instance check / exclude type parameter

Tags: java, generics, casting

Problem.

A `Detect` can supply a **specific type** of `Detectables`, which look like

```
interface Detectable
{/*...*/}

interface Some_detectable extends Detectable
{/*...*/}
```

A `supply` method in `Detect` should be able to accept **any** `Detectable` and only supply it if it is of a **specific type**. I imagine the described situation like this

```
abstract
class Detect<D extends Detectable>
{
  private final Set<D>
  DETECT= new LinkedHashSet<>();

  void
  supplying(Detectable d)
  {
    /*[ DETECT.add(d); ]*/
    /*supply d if of type D*/
  }
}
```

Attemps.

First I tried to make a method to accept `D` and another method handles the case when the argument is not `D` but just any `Detectable`.

Unfortunately I am not able to exclude `D` from the second method or the class type `D`.

Therefore, these methods may result in an ambiguous method (if `D` is the raw `Detectable`)

```
abstract
class Detect<D extends Detectable>
{
  /*...*/
  void
  supplying(D d)
  {
    DETECT.add(d);
  }
  void
  supplying(Detectable d){}
}
```

My current *working*, but *ugly* attempt to solve the problem.

```
abstract
class Detect<D extends Detectable>
{
  final Set<D>
  DETECT= new LinkedHashSet<>();

  void
  supplying(Detectable d)
  {
    D
    casted= try_cast(d);

    if(casted==null) {return;}
    DETECT.add(casted);
  }

  abstract protected D
  try_cast(Detectable detectable);
}

class
Some_detect
extends Detect<Some_detectable>
{
  @Override protected Some_detectable
  try_cast(Detectable d)
  {
    return d instanceof Some_detectable
           ? (Some_detectable)d
           : null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to store an object of class `Class<D>` and use it to check class of `d`. Java generics are erased at runtime, so you can't write something like `d instanceof D` without storing this class.

Here's example code (sorry, I edited your code to correspond to Java code style):

```
interface Detectable {}
interface SomeDetectable extends Detectable {}

abstract class Detect<D extends Detectable> {
    private final Class<D> dClass;
    private final Set<D> detect = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    protected Detect(Class<D> dClass) {
        this.dClass = dClass;
    }

    void supplying(Detectable d) {
        if (dClass.isInstance(d)) {
            detect.add(dClass.cast(d));
        }
    }
}

class SomeDetect extends Detect<SomeDetectable> {
    SomeDetect() {
        super(SomeDetectable.class);
    }
}
```

You can make your base class `Detect<D>` easier to use by automatically finding out type parameter in this particular case, because it's actually stored in class metadata. But it is a fragile approach and I don't generally recommend it.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was searching for! Well written! Thank you very much!